# Custom Authorization for SharePoint document libraries not based on acls in content db

Tags: claims

I need fine grained permissions on SharePoint document libraries not based on acls in the SharePoint content database.

We maintain a seperate SQL Server database containing organizational structures and mapping to SharePoint document libraries. This sql database should be the leading system for authorization permissions on document libraries. It supports groups as well as individual permissions, permission inheritance and cross-ownership permissions.

Creating the ACLs on the sharepoint document libraries (syncing the acls to the database) would be far too tedious even when using code to maintain the permissions.

What would be the best option to implement such a fine grained permission model? We also need SharePoint search results (and possibly FAST) to be trimmed accordingly.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Did you get any reference for this? I have the same problem now!